# Mock an object which is not injected

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm new to Java programming and I have the following code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

public class Foo {
    private final Client http;
    Foo() {
        http = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(CurlRequestFactory.getCurlRequestFactory().get(LOGGER, “someString”));
    }

    public someMethod() {
        Invocation.Builder request = http.target(getURI(“someUri”)).request().header(“someHeader”, “someValue”);
        Response response = request.get();
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test for `someMethod()` where `request.get()` would throw an exception. For this I require that `request` object should be set as a mock object.
But I'm unable to do so as it is being initialized directly instead of getting injected.

I know I can mock an object if it was getting injected as below:

```
Response responseMock = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
Mockito.when(responseMock.get()).thenThrow(new Exception("someMessage"));
```

But I couldn't find anything which works for my scenario.

PS: I don't want to use Powermock.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across few things that Mokito does not support. One is this scenario. Either you have to change your code to inject it or use [PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor). I don't think there is any other option.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is probably doing too many things. I imagine that you don't want to just return the Response from someMethod. Refactor your code to someMethod(Response response) or even better someMethod(Pojo responseBody) and then test that.

I don't know what your use case is, but someMethod probably belongs to another class (I'll call it Bar) separate from the http client class (Foo). You can then inject Foo into Bar and do the test. Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to refactor to that?